# Happy is to Smile as Sad is to...?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, emotions

As the title asks, what is the best name for the expression made with the mouth when sad?

To expand, frowning involves furrowing the brow, crying involves... crying. You can look sullen, you can pout or wince but these all convey specific emotions relating to the broader emotion of sadness.

Smiling on the other hand conveys happiness, and the multiple 'sub-emotions' (excitement, contentment, etc) to happiness.

So is there a word that conveys the upturned smile, without being specific to one type of sadness?

EDIT:
k1eran suggested adding from my comments that Thesaurus.com offers the antonyms frown and glower, both relating to specific angry emotions. Other sites list, again, either expressions relating to specific versions of sadness, expressions which aren't the opposite of smiles (eg. pursed lips) or just the emotions themselves.

Comment: frown or cry depending on context

Comment: or perhaps *pout*.

Comment: Adding a word or two suggested as an antonym by a thesaurus would help your case (even if they sound totally inappropriate).

Comment: Thesaurus.com offers the antonyms frown and glower, both relating to specific angry emotions. Other sites list, again, either expressions relating to specific versions of sadness, expressions which aren't the opposite of smiles (eg. pursed lips) or just the emotions themselves.

Comment: @RowanS that content is helpful and belongs in the question itself

Comment: What, pray tell, is wrong with "frown"?

Comment: [This article](http://www.messagetoeagle.com/ancient-greek-costumes-masks-and-theater/) about ancient Greek theater and masks, says "Tragic masks carried mournful or pained expressions while comic masks were smiling or leering."  I can't develop this into a full answer because it is too late here.  Anyone who wants to use this in an answer, feel free.

Comment: A "frown" does not necessarily imply anger.  It quite commonly reflects disappointment, eg.

Comment: @HotLicks Because as mentioned in the OP, frowning specifically involves furrowing the brow.

Comment: @ab2 - Too late?

Comment: @aparente001 -- no not too late, I +1-ed it.

Comment: @ab2 - I didn't understand why you said "it's too late here" for your idea for an answer.  Nothing's been accepted yet.

Comment: @aparente001 I meant it was too late here in my time zone and I was too tired to work up a full answer, particularly because the web-site I found was difficult to work with.

Comment: @ab2 - - I see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about *sag*?  Your mouth can sag and your whole face and body, in fact, can sag, when you feel sad.

When your mouth sags, it goes down.

You can also say that your *spirit sagged*.

I think this is related to being depressed.  If you think about a depression being a low spot.

Comment: Mouth sagged is interesting, and I like all the arguments you make for it!

Comment: @RowanS - Do you want to wait and see what else comes in, or do you want to click on the checkmark to "accept" the answer?  I'm asking because I think you might be new to Stackexchange.  (Glad you found "sag" interesting!)

Comment: I've actually been lurking for a year or so now, this was just the first time I had a question to ask. I wanted to see if any other answers came up, but I'll accept yours for the reasons stated. :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I agree with your premise that *smile* conveys happiness. One could smile sarcastically, wryly, evilly, lustily, etc. That point aside, I would argue, based your premise, that:

> Happy is to smile and sad is to **smile upside down**.

Of course, we've heard the opposite phrase -- "*turn that frown upside down*" -- in movies and songs. In other words, "Be happy".

Comment: I guess it might not be perfect, but I'd argue all of those examples involve a form of happiness. Smiling sarcastically is an imitation of it, wryly shows amusement, evilly because you're happy about something 'evil', same goes for lustily.

Comment: Upside-down smile... I guess would do in a pinch, it certainly describes it accurately, but I would like to see if there's something else that would work without needing smile as the base.

Comment: @RowanS Thanks. Re your second comment: I understand. Just trying to provide a logical answer that might work for you. Re your first comment: I don't agree that  all smiles connote "happiness" as used in your question ("excitement", "contentment", etc.). Perhaps it's just semantics, but I don't see the underlying "sub-emotions" in my examples as conveying "happiness" *per se*. I could have used other examples, e.g., *smiled with disdain*, *smiled in disbelief*, *smiled hatefully*. It seems to me that both smiles and frowns can convey a variety of mental states beyond simply "happy" and "sad".

Answer (score 1):

A [lugubrious look](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lugubrious) is a good antonym of a smile. It is very general and can be used relating to a [synthetic emotion](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/lugubrious) as can a smile.

It is not a single word and is not as widely known as smile but it is about as close as you can get to a proper antonym.

Comment: It doesn't quite fit, but it is a cool, new, interesting word for me to learn!